# Getting a notification after a general protection exception occurred - Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is it possible to make my Kernel driver get a notification (Some callback routine) when there's a general protection exception?

Will be better if it is possible to achieve this without kernel hooking (Kprobes/Jprobes).

Answer (score 0):

look at `register_die_notifier()` and `unregister_die_notifier()` and their use.

There is an example here.
http://www.linux-mag.com/id/2711/

Comment: I tried registering a die notifier but my callback function does not get called when there's a general protection exception (For example, running a privileged instruction). I used the given example

Comment: There are other notifiers as well. Try those. General protection exception is not really die event, is it?

Comment: This mechanism works only within the Kernel (Kernel elements inform each other about events). That is not what I was looking for. I'm looking for a kernel mechanism that allows me to get a notification when a user process does some 'illegal' things (Like invalid Opcode, running privileged instruction etc).

Comment: Usually CPU generates faults for those things. You have to find fault handler (it might be even assembly code) and check what is done there.